# where is androidviewclient 4.6.0 binary file?

Tags: androidviewclient

I am writing test script for android applications. I have used AndroidViewClient version 3.0.1. But I have just found that AndroidViewClient was updated.

I just want to use this new version of AndroidViewClient 4.6.0, but i cannot find binary file,  I mean, *.jar. Do I have to make it myself? or Where can I download it?

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is not needed any more. **AndroidViewClient >= 4.0.0** is now pure python.
You only need python installed on your computer and that's it.